# How do the choices at the end of the Grissom Academy mission affect my War Assets?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During the Grissom Academy mission, it's mentioned how the children there have been trained in "biotic artillery" strikes and such, but they may be a bit too green for the actual battlefield. At the very end of the mission, you get to decide what to have them do, either join the Alliance as biotic support or join in a more offensive role.

I ended up being a bit of a softy in this case and chose what seemed to be the more Paragon choice of having them do support rather than offense (I blame reading the novels and ending up fond of Kahlee's character in them. Except Deception, because that one's *awful*).

As a result, the "103rd Marine Division" war asset of the Alliance received a 50 point boost for the biotic support. What kind of boost do they get if you take the offense route?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you choose the "They're ready for battle." Renegade option, the students will be made into a Biotic Company in the Alliance. This adds 75 War Asset points in addition to Renegade points.

You will still be able to receive the 20 point bonus for Kahlee Sanders and the bonus for allowing Grissom Academy students/instructors access to the citadel.