# What is the impact of forming the students into a Biotic Company?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Grissom Academy: Emergency Evacuation we can choose between having the students in a support role or having them be a front line force.

This either improves the 103rd Marine Divison (+50 strength) or activates the Biotic Company (+75 strength) War Assets.

Are there other consequences, such as dialogues which will not appear, from this action?

For example are the War Assets for Jack and Kahlee Sanders added regardless of your choice?  Will the option to allow Citadel entry for Grissom instructors and students still appear at the Spectre terminal regardless of your choice?

Comment: To note: I had the 103rd Marine Division *before* this mission. Their entry was simply updated afterwards.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I've reworded to reflect this.

Comment: The motivation for this question comes from a comment I read when looking up the %ages which said "but don't forget to think about future consequences other than just the war assets numbers"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the choices at the end of the Grissom Academy mission affect my War Assets?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55386/how-do-the-choices-at-the-end-of-the-grissom-academy-mission-affect-my-war-asset)

Comment: @Shadur I'd suggest it's an extension of that question as this one doesn't ask about war assets and the other doesn't ask about other after effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will meet Jack in Purgatory some time later and she will tell how the kids are doing. Her dialogue will be different depending on your choice. It doesn't look like there are other consequences beyond that.

Comment: This happens regardless of where you send the kids.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, that's what I meant. The dialogue is different.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the War Asset and dialogue, there's some ending consequences (assuming you pick an ending that leaves anyone alive). Spoilers below:

> Sending them into combat gets them killed.

Answer (score 0):

The War Asset bonuses for allowing access from the Spectre terminal and for Kahlee Sanders will appear regardless of the choice you make.

The dialogue with Jack will change depending on which route you go.